# QLabel text alignment with rich text and <tt>

Tags: qt, layout

I have a QLabel that's displaying rich text (i. e. a subset of HTML supported by Qt) and uses the `<tt>` tag (for monospaced font). This seems to mess up the vertical alignment of the whole label text (not just the monospaced part).

As an example, here are 9 QLabels in a grid layout. The text of the center label is `"Text<tt>Label</tt>"`, while the text of the other labels is `"TextLabel"`. The text of the center label is aligned 3 pixels lower than the others.

[image: Screenshot]

Needless to say, this messes up the layout and causes annoying layout changes when the text is changed to a value that doesn't contain any monospaced font.

How can I get the text to align with the other labels?

Qt 5.5.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome 3.18.2.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: Using `<span style="font-family: monospace">...</span>` instead of `<tt>...</tt>` fixed the issue for me.

Looking at the following screenshot, my impression is that this is an issue related to the Courier New font:

- The blue label (top) has its font set to Courier New. It has additional space above the text.
- The red label (center) uses `<tt>` as in the question. Qt chooses Courier New as a font and it has additional space above the text.
- The green label (bottom) uses `font-family: monospace` as described above (for the "Label" part of the text); Qt chooses a different monospaced font (not sure which one) and spacing is fine.

[image]